# mysql update base on where id in select join too slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using mysql 5.6.

I have following sql:

```
update booking set status=1 where id in(
    select VD.b_id from tableA VD inner join tableB V on VD.v_id=V.id
    where V.type > 2 and V.status not in (1,2) and VD.b_id>0
    and abs(VD.amount) - abs(VD.l_amount) > 1)
```

its explain is:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>select_type</th>
<th>table</th>
<th>type</th>
<th>possible_keys</th>
<th>key</th>
<th>key_len</th>
<th>ref</th>
<th>rows</th>
<th>Extra</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>PRIMARY</td>
<td>booking</td>
<td>index</td>
<td></td>
<td>PRIMARY</td>
<td>4</td>
<td></td>
<td>152070</td>
<td>Using where</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>DEPENDENT SUBQUERY</td>
<td>V</td>
<td>range</td>
<td>PRIMARY,FK_VOUCHER_TYPE_VTID</td>
<td>FK_VOUCHER_TYPE_VTID</td>
<td>4</td>
<td></td>
<td>79652</td>
<td>Using index condition; Using where</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>DEPENDENT SUBQUERY</td>
<td>VD</td>
<td>ref</td>
<td>FK_VOUCHER_DETAIL_VID</td>
<td>FK_VOUCHER_DETAIL_VID</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>CDS.V.ID</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>Using where</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

however, this update statement is too slow, it is executing until mysql timeout(10 mins).

booking has PK id which is auto increment, tableA has PK id with auto increment and foreign key v_id reference id of tableB.

b_id of tableA is from booking id, but there is no foreign key between booking and tableA.

if I only run subquery

> select VD.id ...

, it only return 5 rows.

**but** if I use select * to enclose select VD.id like next:

```
update booking set status=1 where id in( 
select * from (
            select VD.b_id from tableA VD inner join tableB V on VD.v_id=V.id
            where V.type > 2 and V.status not in (1,2) and VD.b_id>0
            and abs(VD.amount) - abs(VD.l_amount) > 1) t
)
```

then this update statement only takes 2 seconds.

its explain is:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>select_type</th>
<th>table</th>
<th>type</th>
<th>possible_keys</th>
<th>key</th>
<th>key_len</th>
<th>ref</th>
<th>rows</th>
<th>Extra</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>PRIMARY</td>
<td>booking</td>
<td>index</td>
<td></td>
<td>PRIMARY</td>
<td>4</td>
<td></td>
<td>152070</td>
<td>Using where</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>DEPENDENT SUBQUERY</td>
<td>&lt;derived3&gt;</td>
<td>index_subquery</td>
<td>&lt;auto_key0&gt;</td>
<td>&lt;auto_key0&gt;</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>func</td>
<td>7965</td>
<td>Using index</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>DERIVED</td>
<td>V</td>
<td>ALL</td>
<td>PRIMARY,FK_VOUCHER_TYPE_VTID</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>217193</td>
<td>Using where</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>DERIVED</td>
<td>VD</td>
<td>ref</td>
<td>FK_VOUCHER_DETAIL_VID</td>
<td>FK_VOUCHER_DETAIL_VID</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>CDS.V.ID</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>Using where</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

om/WwyLB.png

Comment: Please include output for the `explain` for each query

Comment: @Bohemian I added the `explain`, please check, thanks

Comment: The id can be gleaned right from the index, while an entire row, as signaled by `*`, requires actually touching the table, and the query planner (mistakenly) assumes that a full scan is the cheapest option for that. Try running `analyze table` for the tables involved.

Comment: @frank 9000 has good advice. try `analyze booking, tablea, tableb`, then run explain again. Also, can you paste the explain as plain text please?

Comment: @9000 sorry, I don't quite understand, do you mean that there is something wrong with the id index in `update booking where id in (select vd.id ..)`, therefore it is far more slower than `update booking where id in (select * ...`(full scan in select *) ?

Comment: @frank: I just think that the query planner is puzzled by the current structure of the query, and suspect that `*` might be the culprit, I'd try mentioning the desired columns explicitly. Or maybe it's just the jump from the index (which already contains the id) to the actual table row (which stores the other fields) is so expensive, but this seems improbable.

Comment: @9000 I tried as you said, but there is no any improvement after I used `analyze booking, tableA, tableB`

Comment: @Bohemian I pasted the explain as plain text in html table format, please check